# I can't remove item from the cart

Tags: java, spring-boot, cart

Does not remove items from cart.
When I hit "delete" the items are still there.
Only performs the total price calculation. Cart isn't repository , instead Fiction item is a repositry entity , saved in the database
Thanks for your help
This is my code :

```
@Component
public class Cart {

    private List <Fiction> fictions = new ArrayList<Fiction> ();
    
    private float totale = 0.0f;
        
        public Cart() {
        super();
    }
    
    
    public void add(Fiction fiction) {
        
        fictions.add(fiction);
        this.totale = totale + fiction.getPrezzo();
    }
    
    public void remove(Fiction fiction) {
        Iterator<Fiction> iterator = fictions.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Fiction item = iterator.next();
            if(item.equals(fiction)) {
                iterator.remove();
                }
        } this.totale = totale - fiction.getPrezzo();
    }
```

controller

```
Does not remove items from cart.
When I hit "delete" the items are still there.
Only performs the total price calculation.
Thanks for your help
This is my code :  

@Controller
public class CartController {

    @Autowired
    Cart carrello;
    
    @Autowired
    private FictionRepo fictionRepo;
    
  
    
    @RequestMapping("/deleteToCart/{id}")
    public String deleteToCart(@PathVariable("id") Long id ) {
        Fiction fictions = fictionRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Fiction non trovata"));
        System.out.println(" sto per cancellare");
        carrello.remove(fictions);
        System.out.println(" ho cancellato");
        return "redirect:/indexCart";
    }

}
```

Comment: Edit question to share `Fiction`. Did you override `equals()` and `hashCode()` properly?

Comment: What does `items are still there` mean? Does the item not get removed from the `private List <Fiction> fictions` or are you talking about some frontend displaying the items?

Comment: the item not get removed from the list

Comment: BTW your `remove(Fiction fiction)` in a loop removes *all* items equal to `fiction`, but later after the loop you are executing `this.totale = totale - fiction.getPrezzo();` which reduces total price by only *one* `fiction` (even if more would be removed, or even if none was removed). You should update the price each time you remove item in a loop, not after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `equals` to get your code working. Refer the following example:

```java
  // Overriding equals() to compare two Fiction objects
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {

    // If the object is compared with itself then return true
    if (o == this) {
      return true;
    }

        /* Check if o is an instance of Fiction or not
          "null instanceof [type]" also returns false */
    if (!(o instanceof Fiction)) {
      return false;
    }

    // typecast o to Fiction so that we can compare data members
    Fiction c = (Fiction) o;

    // Compare the data members and return accordingly
    return this.id.equals(c.getId());
  }
```

Comment: where's the hashCode? Also, it 's probably better to compare the actual properties of the object, rather than the id